# VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)

Tags: virtualbox, iso

Please read before you vote duplicate;

I have this error:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).
```

I have tried Enabling PAE/NX, Disabling  PAE/NX and neither worked.

Also, I have increased my RAM to the maximum before I get an error, 5309MB.
If I increase my ram higher I get `Invalid Settings Detected`. (not when I boot up, it says on the settings/system/motherboard.

It boots for a quarter second and gives me the error.

Any help appreciated, I have tried just about every online solution I could find but none seemed to change a thing.

OS: Windows 8 x86 Bit and I installed as Windows 8 x32 Bit so I'm not sure if thats a problem.

Comment: It's telling you that VT-x is disabled in the BIOS.  Did you confirm that VT-x is enabled in BIOS?  Even today, many computers are shipped with the VT-x feature disabled, so you need to access BIOS during startup and specifically activate it.

Comment: @Aenimated1 i cannot access bios, it does not let me startup, and it just gives me the error

Comment: No, I mean on your host machine.  VirtualBox utilizes VT-x on your host to improve the performance of the VM, so it's telling you that you need to enable that feature on your host machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am new to Virtual box myself. Faced the same issue and found the fix to be:

1. Enable virtualization from BIOS setup
2. Enable PAE/NX in virtual box

Though I do not have an x86 machine so cannot check for that.

Hope this helps.